# Sculpt brushes not functioning properly

Tags: texturing, sculpting, sculpt

I'm a total newb to Blender, so I don't know if this is a simple problem, but I'm following a tutorial and am currently learning how to use the sculpt tools. However, while the tutorial is showing very smooth and predictable results, my brushes aren't reacting the same way. I've tried several brushes, and most of them are producing a similar result. The flatten brush is only flattening along the sides, but it's not making a stroke like it seems like it's supposed to. All the other brushes are malfunctioning as well. Sculpt/draw, crease, and Nudge make similar strokes, nothing at all like their example images, and nothing at all like I've seen they're supposed to.

I have smoothening on, dyntopo is on, all of my modifiers are applied, so there are no actives ones. I tried applying the scale of my object, and the scale, but none of those solutions have solved the problem. I've searched in all of the forums I could find and still haven't found anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The tutorial I'm following:

[image: Tutorial]

My results trying the same:
[image: Results are buggy]

Comment: did you play around with the detail size in the dynotopo settings to get more resolution on the mesh when you make a stroke? Do you have a pressure sensitive tablet with pressure enabled on the brush?

Answer (score 2):

Just figured it out. I had to apply the modifiers to my object.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thank you for this simple answer! That was exactly my issue, having to first apply the subdivision surface modifier.